# Check if all Child-Components have been mounted

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to detect if the childs have been mounted? When i initialize the Isotope, all children components must be mounted for the initialize. With a timeout of 5ms it is working like expected, but im sure there is a better way.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var container = this.refs.vinesOverview.getDOMNode();

    setTimeout(function() {
      var isotope = new Isotope(container, {
        itemSelector: ".vine_item",
        layoutMode: "masonry",
        resizable: true,
        gutter: 0,
        isFitWidth: true
      });

      this.setState({ isotope: isotope });
    }.bind(this), 5);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried now this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var container = this.refs.vinesOverview.getDOMNode();
    console.log(container.offsetHeight); // console output 0
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(container.offsetHeight); // console output 3150
    }, 5);
  },
```

So after 5ms it has calculated the height? Thats the reason why isotope isn't working. Is that a Bug or is that normal? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

React waits to mount all child components before calling `componentDidMount` on the parent. If you find a repro case where this isn't true, please file a bug.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I have updated my question with something i have found out.

Comment: Determining when layout happens isn't something React has control over. I'd guess that you have something else affecting your code -- when componentDidMount is called, React is completely done touching the DOM (except for special cases like ReactTransitionGroup where another update gets enqueued).

Comment: Thanks i have found the error! I was loading the data via ajax in componentWillMount, and set the state there. So it was first mounting, loading data, and then remounting.

Comment: Passing the Data via props helped, so it was directly initialized.

Comment: Maybe all children components are mounted when the parent's `componentDidMount` method is called, but react calls `componentDidMount` of the parent before `componentDidMount` of the children. Should I file a bug?

Comment: Same as JulienD, parent componentDidMount is called before the inner componentDidMount's