# Find out from parent component that child component is mounted in react

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a react component, which has a child component. I have to know in parent component that the child component is mounted. How to do that?

Comment: `componentDidMount` in the parent will only be called if all the child components are already mounted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734862/check-if-all-child-components-have-been-mounted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all Child-Components have been mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734862/check-if-all-child-components-have-been-mounted)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of React you are using.

If you are using React version 16.8 or higher, you can use the useEffect hook in the child component which can trigger a function in the parent component.

```
const Parent = props => {
 const OnChildMount = () => {
  console.log('Child Mounted);
 }
 return (
  <Child onMount={OnChildMount}/>
 )
}

const Child = props => {
 useEffect(() => {
  props.onMount();
 }, []);

 return (
  //The child JSX
 );
}
```

The empty brackets [] in the useEffect hook makes sure that it only runs when the Child component is mounted.

If you are using older versions of React, you can use the ComponentDidMount lifecycle hook in the child component to trigger the same function in the Parent.

This being said, the final solution would actually depend on your exact requirement.